# Adding webpage link to each data point or data label on an Excel scatter plot

Tags: excel, vba

I have three columns of data x value, y value, and a corresponding webpage link to each set of xy values. Is it possible to add the hyperlinks to the scatter plot, so when I click on a data point or data label it opens the link webpage in a browser?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. But for this, you will have to place the chart in a separate chart sheet. Once you have set the chart, in the VBA code, use the chart event Chart_Select(). For example

```
Private Sub Chart_Select(ByVal ElementID As Long, _
ByVal Arg1 As Long, ByVal Arg2 As Long)
    'Debug.Print "Element: " & ElementID
    'Debug.Print "  Arg 1: " & Arg1
    'Debug.Print "  Arg 2: " & Arg2
    
    '~~> Please change as required.
    If ElementID = 3 Then
        Select Case Arg2
        
        Case 1: ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "http:\\Google.Com", NewWindow:=True
        Case 2: ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "http:\\Gmail.Com", NewWindow:=True
        Case 3: ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink "http:\\Msn.Com", NewWindow:=True
        
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

This should get you started. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: How do I return the cell address of the data point in the chart. So I can use the link stored in the cell next to it?

Comment: @PoliDoli: First Create a Chart and then use the above code (uncomment the debug.print and comment the rest) and find out the values of ElementID and Arg2. See what values are returned when you click on the datapoints. After that simply trap those values and pickup the web address from the relevant Excel Cells :)